# Closest-point and farthest-point Voronoi diagrams

Tags: algorithm, theory, voronoi

There is a problem in my book that uses the concept of closest-point and farthest-point Voronoi diagrams to construct a minimum width annulus for a set of points (used in coordinate measurement machines).

**What I need to know:**

Say you construct the closest-point voronoi diagram (CPVD) and the farthest-point voronoi diagram (FPVD) on a set of points P. What is an efficient way to find the intersections between the CPVD's edges and the FPVD's edges (if you overlay the two diagrams) if you know there are only O(n) intersections.

I just can't think of a way that is faster than O(n^2). Is there some property I'm glossing over?

Comment: Use [Bentley--Ottmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley–Ottmann_algorithm)? The diagrams have no self-intersections, so you don't need one of the red-blue algorithms.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if it that is what the writers expected, but it seems legitimate to me.

Comment: @user2983963 What is *your book*?